# user-defined java Script function doesn't work properly till being followed by standard one

Tags: javascript

I have a function `myFun()` that is called when a user pressed the ENTER key on the keyboard. The function `myFun()` calls another user-defined function `callFun()`.

I've added this event to the input item which will be triggered once ENTER key is pressed: `onkeydown="myFun();"`.

This is the structure of my function:

```
function myfunc() {
      if (window.event.keyCode === 13)
       {
         callFun();
        // alert("DONE");     
      }
}
```

Now, it will not be executed unless `alert("DONE")` is uncommented, otherwise it's not executed.

/+/+/+/+/+ More Explanation +++++\
now, user has two choice either click on a button "btn1" or press the ENTER key. So, once the user click the button btn1 everything goes fine. but once he/she press the ENTER Key, function myfunc() will be executed and call callFun(). function myfunc() will send a parameter which is an aspx page to the callFun(). the problem is that the callFun() will not be executed unless followed by alret() function and this happened by chance when I was debugging the code. So, I don't need the alret() at all but I noticed it is executed one I use it. this means there is somthing happen with the alret(). I hope this is clear. Thanks

Comment: You don't give us enough information to help with this. Where is `callFun` defined? How is it loaded into the environment? It sounds like a chronology issue.

Comment: There's a technique I use with some success which is called "debugging". They also have these tools called "debuggers" to help you with "debugging". Have you looked into that?

Comment: Show us the definition of `callFun`, please. Does it work if you move the alert into there?

Comment: this is the structure: myFunc() will call callFunc(default.aspx); then, callFunc() will do this code: window.location = url + '?p1=' + document.getElementById('inputtxt').value; url is the received page

Comment: can you [edit] your question and post the code there, in a formatted and readable way? Thanks :-)

Comment: The only reason I can think of without seeing complete code, is if you have some async code in your callFunc and then have something strange happening after your callFun(); line. What will happen then is that alert will stop execution, but the async stuff in callFun will still happen and have a chance to complete, but without alert whatever happens after callFun will block the async stuff in callFun. But please post your exact code (you have already said that you send an aspx file to callFun, but that can't be seen in your examples, also post complete callFun code

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" onKeyDown="endterText()"></input>
<script>
    function endterText(){
      if (window.event.keyCode === 13)
       {
            setTimeout((function(){callFun();}),1000)
            alert("DONE");     
      }
}
function callFun(){
    console.log('this is cool')
}
window.alert = function ( text ) { console.log( 'tried to alert: ' + text ); return true; };
</script>
```

please follow the link ..

http://jsfiddle.net/zcfkzaod/1/

is alert is blocking your code of execution  ?
do u want to disable your alert(); ?
or the code is not working .. ?

Comment: No. the order has no effect

Comment: alert block the javascript execution until  callFun() is in scope .
try to add a setTimeout function .

setTimeout((function(){callFun();}),1000) ..